# MongoDB cannot start WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Afer an automatic update on GKE, recreation of a pod with MongoDB image fails.
Stack trace follows:

```
2019-09-23T09:13:30.430+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mongod-0
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.14
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: cbef87692475857c7ee6e764c8f5104b39c342a1
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" }, replication: { replSet: "MainRepSet" }, security: { authorization: "enabled", clusterAuthMode: "keyFile", keyFile: "/etc/secrets-volume/mongodb-auth-keyfile" }, setParameter: { authenticationMechanisms: "SCRAM-SHA-1" } }
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-09-23T09:13:30.431+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=2723M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-09-23T09:13:31.115+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (95) [1569230011:115812][1:0x7f9d4b73aa40], wiredtiger_open: __wt_conn_compat_config, 226: Version incompatibility detected: required max of 3.0cannot be larger than saved release 3.1: Operation not supported
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 E -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:95: Operation not supported src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 486
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28595: 95: Operation not supported, terminating
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-09-23T09:13:31.116+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: It might help https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36974